# How move between activity in android?

Tags: android, database

I am building an android application where the user will a from that is local registration from.

The user fill data like name, email and phone number. This all data are save on server.

I need is that this activity of user-from should only run when application is lauch first time in any android phone!

Now what happen is after Splash screen user-from apper then main screen always when ever the application is open. I need is that after Splash screen user should displayed with main screen content if he is using the application after the initial launch after filling the user-form screen data!

Please help me!!

Comment: You need to save somewhere whether the user already entered his data, then check this at `onCreate` and decide what `Activity` to show.

Comment: sometimes please google.. there are wild solutions & advancements here on SO, about and around your problem and requirements

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Answer (score 0):

Use that kind of code to switch between two activities depending on a parameter.

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    if (prefs.getBoolean("first_launch", true))
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        prefs.edit().putBoolean("first_launch", false).commit();
    }
    else
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DefaultActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
//If you need pass data in a Second Activity
    intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", sessionId);
    startActivity(intent)
```